# The meaning of `this` in JS template method pattern

Tags: javascript, module-pattern, template-method-pattern

Why does the marked line fail to find `protectedACMember`?

```
var Module = (function (ns) {

    function AbstractClass() {
        this.protectedACMember = "abstract";

        this.abstractPublicACMethod = function (input) {
            this.methodToImplement();                   
        }
    }

    ConcreteClass.prototype = new AbstractClass();
    function ConcreteClass(){
        var privateCCMember = "private CC";

        var privateCCMethod = function(){
            alert(this.protectedACMember); // cant find protectedACMember
        }

        this.methodToImplement = function(){ 
            privateCCMethod();
            console.log('Implemented method '); 
        }

    }

    ns.ConcreteClass = ConcreteClass;   

    return ns;

})(Module || {});

//somewhere later
var cc = new Module.ConcreteClass();
cc.abstractPublicACMethod();
```

are there any good patterns for simulating private, protected and public members? Static/non-static as well?

Comment: really good current book about js design patterns:
http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change that part of code like this:

```
    var self = this;
    var privateCCMethod = function(){
        alert(self.protectedACMember); // this -> self
    }
```

This way you get the reference in the closure.

The reason is, that "this" is a reserved word, and its value is set by the interpreter. Your privateCCMethod is an anonymous function, not the object property, so if you call it simply by privateCCMethod() syntax, this will be null. 
If you'd like "this" to be bound to something specific you can always use .call syntax, like this:

```
privateCCMethod.call(this)
```

Comment: what if I wrote `function privateCCMethod() {...}` - would it be a property of the object then?

Comment: No. In the code from your example "methodToImplement" is the property. This is one way of doing it. The other, would be to define it like ConcereteClass.prototype.privateCCMethod = function() {...}.

Answer (score 0):

It fails to find `protectedACMember` because what the `this` keyword means changes when you enter the function `privateCCMethod`. A common practice is to store the outer `this` for use inside the functions:

```
function ConcreteClass(){
    var privateCCMember = "private CC";

    // store the outer this
    var that = this;
    var privateCCMethod = function(){
        alert(that.protectedACMember);
    }
    ...
```

The rest of your questions are fairly loaded and should probably be posted as a separate question.

Comment: `this` is always the nearest enclosing function? what if I skipped `this` and simply wrote `alert(protectedACMember)`?

Comment: @Queequeg it would look for a scoped variable named `protectedACMember` and would not find anything. `protectedACMember` is a property of the object.

Comment: is setting the `that` variable better than using `func.call(this,...)` ?

Comment: @Queequeg yes; providing the proper context for `protectedACMember` is the responsibility of `privateCCMethod`, not the consumer of the function.

Comment: I meant the call inside `methodToImplement`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to ensure that `this` means what you want is to use `bind`. Bind allows you to ensure a function is called with a specific value of `this`.

Most newer browsers support it (even IE9!) and there's a workaround for those that don't.

[Bind - MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: it looks like `function.call`